# React Native for MacOS app basic features

Tags: react-native, react-native-macos

Quiet new to RN and I'm trying to build the following app:

A clone of Clipy for MacOS -> https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy

few questions :

- how can I control the max height/width of the app window itself ? (This didn't work)

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  active: {
    height:100,
    width:100,
    maxHeight:100,
    maxWidth:100,
  },
  inactive: {
    height:0,
    width:0,
    fontSize: 0,    
  },
});

 return (
    <View style={styles.active} OR {styles.inactive}>
        <Text>Current state is: {appStateVisible}</Text>
    </View>
  );
```

- How do move app to background/foreground when app is active/inactive ? Meaning a "floating" like feeling which disappears on "click-away" event and appears on keyboard shortcut or something

Thanks a lot !!